# XML XPath - selecting parent text only if child condition is met

Tags: xml, xpath

I am working on a project that requires getting the text from a parent element without getting the text from the decedents only if the title attribute exists in  the child element.

In the example below, I need to get the text '1999' from the `li` element, if and only if, the title attribute exists in the child anchor (`li/i/a/@title`), is this possible? thanks in advance

This is what I tried initially, but this wont work for my use case...
 `//ul/li/text()[last()]`, also tried `//ul/li/text()`

```
<ul>
  <li>
      <i>
        <a href="#apples" title="apples">
          Apples
        </a>
      </i> (1999)
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//li[.//a/@title]/text()[last()]
```

will return the last text node child of those `li` elements with a descendant `a` that has a `@title` attribute:

```
(1999)
```

as requested.

<sub>**Credit**: Simplified `[.//a[@title]]` to `[.//a/@title]` per helpful suggestion by [Allan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8794221/allan).</sub>